# Can I install GCC 4.4.4 on Fedora 29 or downgrade my Fedora version?

Tags: fedora, gcc8, gcc4.4

I have a piece of code that is currently compiling on Fedora 13 (I have it on a VM). I created a new VM using Fedora 29. The issue is that F29 has GCC v8.1 whereas the F13 has GCC v4.4.4 because of which the code is not compiling on F29. I found that using update-alternatives I can install multiple GCC versions. However, I am not able to install gcc4. Does anyone know, how to do it? Or, shall I use some other Fedora version (since the F13 doesn't allow me to install Virtual Box extensions).

I am using Virtual Box 6. I have no idea as I am new to all this.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1449619/can-i-install-gcc-4-4-4-on-fedora-29-or-downgrade-my-fedora-version

Comment: However, if you want to _fix_ your code so that it works with a modern compiler, this would be the place to ask about the errors you are getting and how to fix them.